# How to protect an array from being refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

I have clothes and orders tables and array which based on Clothes and Orders models.Whenever I push a clothes element into Orders array and especially to update amount of clothes and price which selected,Clothes array also being updated as well and I don't want it.I want to keep my array as immutable.I searched for it on the internet but didn't work.Here's what I tried below.Also to make it clear I'll add pictures here

https://imge.to/i/vg2aYm

https://imge.to/i/vg2uvF

**HTML**

```
    <table class="table table-sm">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Clothes</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let i of clothesList;let a = index">
            <td>{{i.name}}</td>
            <td>{{i.price}}$</td>
            <td><button class="btn btn-alert" (click)="onAddItem(i)" >Add To Cart</button></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

   <table class="table" *ngIf="orders.length>0">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Clothes</th>
                        <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                        <th scope="col">Price</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      <tr *ngFor="let order of orders;">
                        <td>{{order.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{order.amount}}</td>
                        <td>{{order.price}}</td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                    <hr>
                    <strong>Total Cost: {{totalCost}}</strong>
                  </table>
```

**TS**

```
export class AppComponent  {
 private clothesList:Clothes[]=[
   new Clothes(1,'Hat',500,1),
   new Clothes(2,'Shoes',150,1),
   new Clothes(3,'Pants',100,1),
   new Clothes(4,'Jacket',200,1),
   new Clothes(5,'T-Shirt',120,1),
   new Clothes(6,'Souvether',150,1),
   new Clothes(7,'Scarf',400,1)
 ];
    private orders:Order[]=[];

    onAddItem(value)
  {   
   if(this.orders.find(i => i.name===value.name))
   {
      let myIndex= this.orders.indexOf(value);
      value.amount++;
      this.orders[myIndex].price+=this.orders[myIndex].price;
   } 
  else
   {
    this.orders.push(value);
   }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the elements inside both the clothes and order array share same reference, You need to deep clone your object to break the reference: 
Try the following:

```
onAddItem(value){
        let order = this.orders.find(i => i.name === value.name);
        if (order) {
            value.amount++;
            order.price *= 2;
        }
        else {
            this.orders.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))); // break the reference
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gives me ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'price' of undefined

Comment: Since now clothes and orders array have different element reference.  let myIndex= this.orders.indexOf(value); so this line will not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
this.orders.push(angular.copy(value));
```

this will add a copy of the object to the orders list an not a reference of it

Comment: Angular isn't recognizable.Is there any additional method to import?

Comment: if you're in an angular application... import angular from 'angular'; wil do it

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by others, the `Clothes` object you're passing in to `onAddItem` is a reference to the corresponding `Clothes` object in `clothesList`, so when you mutate that object, it will mutate the original object.

If `Clothes` is a simple class, you can just use the spread operator to make a copy:

```js
onAddItem(value) {
   let copyOfValue = {...value};
   ...
}
```

You could also use the `Clothes` constructor to make a copy:

```js
onAddItem(value) {
   let copyOfValue = new Clothes(value.someProperty, value.anotherProperty, value.aThirdProperty, value.aFourthProperty);
   ...
}
```